# Can I silence boost's configure script?

Tags: boost

When I'm installing boost (running .configure) it lists every file that is copied in the install process. Is there any way to silence this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By silence, do you mean just prevent output to the screen? You could do `.configure > /dev/null` in Linux/OS X or `.configure > nul` in Windows.

Comment: Yes and no. I don't want to see the 1000+ OK messages but I do want to see the errors. I suppose I could dump it to a file and parse for errors ... thanks, I wasn't even thinking along these lines.